# CSS3 Custom generated fonts are sometimes not showing the proper icons

Tags: css, svg, fonts, gulp, custom-font

Created a font-icons with material svg and custom svg files using [gulp-iconfont-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iconfont-css). Sometimes these font-icons are not appearing with the correct icon they are actually jumbled and on refresh, all icons are arranged properly on the site.

why is it happening like this and how to solve this?

Comment: This might happen when you regenerate the font after adding a new icon. I think you can prevent it by assigning a fixed codepoint to each icon.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, Can you please share some example

Comment: There's an example in the docs: https://github.com/backflip/gulp-iconfont-css/blob/master/test/main.js#L101-L104